# Splitting list by char and int

Tags: python, algorithm

Is there any ways to split like:

```
a = 'a3c11d1c3d3'

output = ['a', '3', 'c', '11', 'd', '1', 'c', '3', 'd', '3']
```

I've tried this like:

```
list(a)
```

However, it gave me the result like:

```
output = ['a', '3', 'c', '1', '1', 'd', '1', 'c', '3', 'd', '3']
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `re.findall` and match alternatively groups of letters or digits:

```py
a = 'a3c11d1c3d3'
output = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+', a)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['a', '3', 'c', '11', 'd', '1', 'c', '3', 'd', '3']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = 'a3c11d1c3d3'
["".join(g) for _, g in groupby(a, key=str.isdigit)]
# ['a', '3', 'c', '11', 'd', '1', 'c', '3', 'd', '3']
```